# How many combination of $3$ integers reach given number?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, generating-functions, integer-partitions

I have 3 numbers

$M=10$

$N=5$

$I=2$

Suppose I have been given number $R$ as input that is equal to $40$

so in how many ways these $3$ numbers arrange them selves to reach $40$

e.g.

$$10+10+10+10$$

$$10+5+5+5+5+10$$

$$5+5+5+5+5+5+5+5$$

etc.

Kow can you give me formulae supposing I pass any number e.g. $30$ etc.

What are formulae to calculate the number of these $3$ integers combinations to given number?

1 MORE EXAMPLE?

suppose number is 7

combinationare 2 these are

5+2

2+5

Comment: Do you consider $10 + 10 + 10 + 5 + 5$ to be different from $5 + 10 + 5 + 10 + 10$?

Comment: yes different things both are also combination

Comment: yes sdifferent because 7 have 5+2   and 2+5

Comment: Are you sure? I think the problem is a lot easier if you consider re-orderings to be the same partition ...

Comment: THE QUESTION IS SIMPLE HOW MANY COMBINATION OF THESE 3 NUMBERS REACH THE GIVEN NUMBER

Comment: check latest example in questions

Comment: There's no need to shout. Just because the question is simple does not mean its answer will be!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a slightly different way to calculate the number of *[compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29)* of $40$ generated from $2,5$ and $10$.

> Since a selection of $2,5$ or $10$ can be represented as
>   \begin{align*}
> x^2+x^5+x^{10}
> \end{align*}
>   we start with the *[ordinary generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Ordinary_generating_function)*
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{1-\left(x^2+x^5+x^{10}\right)}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\left(x^2+x^5+x^{10}\right)^j
> \end{align*}
>   providing the number of occurrences of zero or more selections of $2,5$ or $10$.

We are interested in the coefficient of $x^{40}$ and expand the series accordingly. It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ of a series.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^{40}]&\frac{1}{1-\left(x^2+x^5+x^{10}\right)}\\
> &=[x^{40}]\sum_{j=0}^\infty\left(x^2+x^5+x^{10}\right)^j\\
> &=[x^{40}]\sum_{j=0}^\infty x^{2j}\left(1+x^3+x^7\right)^j\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{20}[x^{40-2j}]\sum_{k=0}^{j}\binom{j}{k}\left(x^3+x^8\right)^k\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{20}[x^{40-2j}]\sum_{k=0}^{j}\binom{j}{k}x^{3k}\left(1+x^5\right)^k\\
> &=\sum_{0\leq k\leq j\leq 20}\binom{j}{k}[x^{40-2j-3k}]\sum_{l=0}^{k}\binom{k}{l}x^{5l}\qquad\qquad 2j+3k\leq 40\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{0\leq l\leq k\leq j\leq 20}\binom{j}{k}\binom{k}{l}\quad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad2j+3k+5l=40\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and the rule
  \begin{align*}
    [x^{n-m}]A(x)=[x^n]x^mA(x)
    \end{align*}
- In (2) we use another notation for summation and respect that the power $40-2j-3k$ is non-negative. In order to get a coefficient with a contribution $>0$ we have to choose $40-2j-3k=5l$. This is done in the next step.

> In (3) we see that for each triple $(j,k,l)$ which fulfills
>
> \begin{align*}
>   &0\leq l\leq k\leq j\leq 20\\
>   &2j+3k+5l=40
>   \end{align*}
>
> we have a contribution of $\binom{j}{k}\binom{k}{l}$.
>
> These triples are
>
> \begin{array}{rrrrr}
>   j&k&l&\binom{j}{k}\binom{k}{l}&\sum\\
> \hline
>   4&4&4&1&1\\
>   5&5&3&10&11\\
>   6&6&2&15&26\\
>   7&7&1&7&33\\
>   8&3&3&56&89\\
>   8&8&0&1&90\\
>   9&4&2&756&846\\
>   10&5&1&1260&2106\\
>   11&6&0&462&2568\\
>   12&2&2&66&2634\\
>   13&3&1&858&3492\\
>   14&4&0&1001&4493\\
>   16&1&1&16&4509\\
>   17&2&0&36&4645\\
>   20&0&0&1&\color{blue}{4646}\\
>   \end{array}
>
> resulting finally in
>
> \begin{align*}
> [x^{40}]&\frac{1}{1-\left(x^2+x^5+x^{10}\right)}=4646
> \end{align*}
>
> in accordance with the result of @WillOrrick.

Comment: how u built triples table u r right

Comment: @EngrNouman: According to (3) we have to sum up the products of binomial coefficients:  $1,1+10=11,11+15=26,\ldots$.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a formula, but it does provide a way to compute the number you want.  Let $f(n,k)$ denote the number $k$-term sums of the numbers $2$, $5$, and $10$ whose value is $n$.  Using the exponential generating function, $f(n,k)$ is the coefficient of $\frac{x^ny^k}{k!}$ in the expansion of $$
G(x,y)=\exp(y(x^2+x^5+x^{10})).
$$
So the coefficient of $x^{40}$ in $G(x,y)$ is
$$
P_{40}(y)=\frac{y^4}{24}+\frac{y^5}{12}+\frac{y^6}{48}+\frac{y^7}{720}+\frac{19
   y^8}{13440}+\frac{y^9}{480}+\frac{y^{10}}{2880}+\frac{y^{11}}{86400}+\frac{y^{12}}{7257600}+\frac{y^{1
   3}}{7257600}+\frac{y^{14}}{87091200}+\frac{y^{16}}{1307674368000}+\frac{y^{17}}{2615348736000}+\frac{y^{20}}{2432902008176640000}.
$$
The number of four-term sums with value $40$ is the coefficient of $\frac{y^4}{4!}$ in this sum, which is $1$; the number of five-term sums is the coefficient of $\frac{y^5}{5!}$, which is $10$; the number of six-term sums is the coefficient of $\frac{y^6}{6!}$, which is $15$; and so on.

**Added:** A systematic way to extract the answer to the question in the original post is to define the differential operator
$$
\mathcal{D}=1+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 y}+\frac{\partial^3}{\partial^3 y}+\ldots.
$$
Then
$$
\left.\mathcal{D}P_{40}(y)\right\rvert_{y=0}=4646.
$$
Applying this operator to $G(x,y)$ gives the single-variable generating function
$$
\left.\mathcal{D}G(x,y)\right\rvert_{y=0}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty(x^2+x^5+x^{10})^j=\frac{1}{1-x^2-x^5-x^{10}}.
$$
One root of the denominator is $-1$.  If one can find all ten roots, then one can perform partial fraction decomposition and get a closed form for all of the coefficients.  Carrying this out numerically gives the formula
$$
(0.142857) (-1.)^n+(0.13495\, -0.118936 i) (-0.977224-0.533462
   i)^n+(0.13495\, +0.118936 i) (-0.977224+0.533462 i)^n+(0.0325019\, -0.00923824 i) (-0.28946-0.81605 i)^n+(0.0325019\,
   +0.00923824 i) (-0.28946+0.81605 i)^n+(0.078652\, +0.0284466 i) (0.357796\, -0.943739 i)^n+(0.078652\, -0.0284466 i)
   (0.357796\, +0.943739 i)^n+(0.0433843\, -0.0370765 i) (0.771384\, +0.483182 i)^n+(0.0433843\, +0.0370765 i) (0.771384\,
   -0.483182 i)^n+(0.278166) (1.27501)^n,
$$
which gives accurate results for $n=40$.  The leading large $n$ asymptotic behavior is given by the last term in this expression,
$$
0.2781662298364124\times (1.2750078449285394)^n.
$$